# How to delete attribute from session in new thread?

Tags: java, tomcat

I write web-app. There is captcha, which saved in session. After create captcha I start new Thread, where as the parameter I pass the HttpServletRequest from the servlet. Next, forward occurs in servlet. The thread sleep for 1 minute, and delete captcha attribute from session. But I get NullPointerExeption. I think it is because the forward was called. How to delete attribute from session in this thread?

My code:

```
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private CaptchaHandler captchaHandler = new CaptchaHandler();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        captchaHandler.createCaptcha(req, resp);
        new MyThread(req).start();
        req.getRequestDispatcher("./register.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}


public class MyThread extends Thread{
        
        private HttpServletRequest req;

        public MyThread(HttpServletRequest req) {
            this.req = req;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            req.getSession().removeAttribute("captcha");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpServletRequest` object is only valid inside the `service` method of your servlet (which calls the `doGet` method). See section 3.13 of the [Servlet Specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf):

> The developer must be aware that maintaining references to request objects for which `startAsync` has not been called outside the scope described above is not recommended as it may have indeterminate results.

Most servlet containers recycle request objects. That's why the `getSession()` method gives you `null`. (Almost) all objects you obtain from a `HttpServletRequest` have the same lifespan, so passing a reference to the `HttpSession` object is no solution either.

I am guessing that your ultimate purpose is to limit the amount of sessions for which a captcha was not solved. In order to do so you can call:

```java
req.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
```

in your `doGet` method and restore a higher value in the captcha solver. This way all sessions for which the captcha was not solved in 60 seconds will be deleted.